# invariant properties between p-group and it's automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a p-group and $Aut(G)$ be group of automorphisms of $G$
which properties of $G$ can help us with studding $Aut(G)$?
for example If $G$ is infinite/finite does this guaranty $Aut(G)$ be infinite/finite?
or knowing order of $G$ can help us with making some limits for order of $Aut(G)$?

Comment: At least if the group $G$ has finite order then the number of set-theoretic mappings between $G$ is finite. Hence $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ has also finite order. In fact, you've got a very rough upper bound $\lvert \operatorname{Aut}(G) \rvert \leq \lvert G \rvert ^{\lvert G \rvert}$.

Comment: finite case is easy, my concern is about infinite case. does infinite $G$ (plus some property) guaranty infinite $Aut(G)$?

Comment: Why did you ask about the finite case if you think it easy?

Comment: my mistake. I thought maybe some kind of infinite p-group $G$ have finite $Aut(G)$

Answer (score 1):

Any infinite torsion group has infinite automorphism group. This is (allegedly) proved in R. Baer, Finite extensions of abelian groups with minimum condition, Trans. Amer. Math.
Soc. 79 (1955), 521-540.